# Including the reflection library in a jar output by kotlinc

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

I'm trying to get the reflection lib included in sample jar, but can't get it to work:

```
$ kotlinc hello.kt -d hello.jar
$ java -jar hello.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
```

The runtime lib was missing, so let's add it:

```
$ kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
$ java -jar hello.jar
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
```

Now the runtime lib is included, but the reflection lib is missing, so let's specify kotlin home directory:

```
$ kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -kotlin-home ~/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/1.1.1 -d hello.jar
$ java -jar hello.jar
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
```

Reflection lib is still not included. `kotlinc` help lists a '`-no-reflect`' option, so I'm assuming the reflection library should be included by default when '`-include-runtime`' is set, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I just ran into this same problem. According to the Kotlin Reflection documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html), distributing the kotlin-reflect.jar file separately is intentional, and you should make sure the .jar file is added to the classpath of your "project". It doesn't actually tell you how to do that from either kotlinc or when running your jar from java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently the `-include-runtime` option only includes the standard Kotlin library (`kotlin-stdlib`) to the resulting jar. You're right in that the reflection library (`kotlin-reflect`) should also be included, unless the `-no-reflect` option is specified. I've created an issue in the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17344

Until the issue is resolved: if you're looking for a way to run the compiled program on your machine only, I recommend you to compile your application to the directory instead of a jar, and then run the main class with the `kotlin` command.

```
kotlinc hello.kt -d output
kotlin -cp output hello.HelloKt
```

If you're planning to distribute the program to other users though, I recommend to use a proper build system like Maven or Gradle and specify `kotlin-stdlib`/`kotlin-reflect` as proper dependencies there, instead of bundling them together with your application in the single jar.